# How can I implement a variable text file name that is defined by the user and then get the 3x3 matrix from it?

Tags: c++, file-io, matrix

I need to to write a program that gets a 3x3 matrix from a user defined file, prints it, and then determine whether it's a [magic square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square).

My latest version has some problems that I can't figure out how to fix, I have been puzzling over this for hours. I've done everything from trying to find solutions on the web for a solution to reviewing the basics again.

I tried David Brown's solution, but I realized we misunderstood each other.

I want the user to enter the file name, the program to get the 3x3 matrix from it (using ifstream), print the matrix, and then determine if it's a magic square.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip> #include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    int row, col, r, c, i, j, k, diag=0;
    int magic[19][19];

    std::string fout = "my_file_name.txt";

    std::ifstream ifs(fout.c_str());

    for(j=0 ; j<n+1 ; j++){
        for(k=0 ; k<n+1 ; k++)
            magic[j][k] = 0;
    }

    row=1;
    col=(n+1)/2;
    magic[row-1][col-1]=1;

    for(i=2 ; i<=(n*n) ; i++){
        row-=1;
        col-=1;

        if(row==0 && col==0){
            col++;
            row+=2
        }
        else if(row==0)
            row=n;
        else if(col==0)
            col=n;
        else if(magic[row-1][col-1]!=0){
            col++;
            row+=2;
        }

        magic[row-1][col-1]=i;
    }

    for(r=0; r<n; r++){
        for(c=0; c<n; c++){
            magic[r][n]+=magic[r][c];
        }
    }

    for(c=0; c<n; c++){
        for(r=0; r<n; r++){
            magic[n][c]+=magic[r][c];
        }
    }

    for(r=0; r<n; r++){
        magic[n][n] += magic[r][r];
    }

    for(r=0; r<n; r++){
        c = n - r + 1;
        diag+=magic[r][c];
    }

    for(r=0; r<(n+1) ; r++){
        fout << endl;
        for(c=0; c<(n+1) ; c++){
            fout << setw (5) << magic[r][c];
        }
        fout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem specifically?

Comment: Compiler provides me with this:  C:\programs\c\maagiav1.cpp: In function `int main()':
C:\programs\c\maagiav1.cpp:56: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'fout << std::endl'

C:\programs\c\maagiav1.cpp:58: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'fout << std::setw(5)'
C:\programs\c\maagiav1.cpp:59: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'fout << std::endl'

Execution terminated

Comment: And the compiler is quite correct, there are no `operator<<` overloads with `std::string` as the left hand argument. Did you mean for `fout` to be some kind of file stream perhaps?

Comment: @David , yeah I wanted to use it as a file stream for the output from the file

Answer (score 0):

`fout` is a `std::string` (constaining "my_file_name.txt"), but you appear to be trying to use it like a `std::ofstream`. Did you mean to declare `fout` as

```
std::ofstream fout("my_file_name.txt");
```

Comment: I tried that solution and then realized that I misunderstood what you guys asked me and you misunderstood me. I want user to enter the file name,the program uses the file name to get 3x3 premade matrix(ifstream)from it then prints it and then analyzes whether it is magical matrix or not.

Answer (score 0):

As David Brown pointed out, you're not using `fout` correctly. It sounds like you actually want to print the matrix to the console. If so, you want ***`cout`*** instead:

```
for(r=0; r<(n+1) ; r++){
    cout << endl;
    for(c=0; c<(n+1) ; c++){
        cout << setw (5) << magic[r][c];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

To get the file name from the user, use `cin` and the `>>` operator. You can read up on it at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/.

To open the file and read its contents, you can use the `ifstream` you've already defined (`ifs`) and the `>>` operator. The previously reference website also has a tutorial on this at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

In fact, you may just want to browse the entire [cplusplus.com tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/). If you have any specific question on either topic, just let me know.